# What does "Every once in a while, however, you’ll find yourself crafting " mean?

Tags: meaning

My English is not good and I'm trying to improve it.  I came across this sentence while reading an article, and I want to know what it means:

> Every once in a while, however, you’ll find yourself crafting.

Comment: What is the context for this? Can you provide some of the text either side of the quote you provided please.

Answer (score 2):

*Every once in a while* is used for infrequent events. Here, you'll do something (crafting) which you don't normally do.

The time interval is not clear, so the meaning must be obvious from the context.

> Every once in a while, it rains in Central Australia and Lake Eyre fills with water.

Which suggests something which might happen at intervals of *decades*.

It's the kind of phrase popular in Children's literature, where precision is not required, and it has a kind of *once upon a time* connotation to it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the sentence ends there?  "Crafting" requires an object, unless its a jargon usage.

E.g. *Every once in a while, however, you'll find yourself crafting the difficult bits that can't be built automatically.*

Comment: No, my wife does *crafting*. It's a bit like *scrapbooking*.

Comment: See http://www.crafting.co.uk/ I assumed the OP was reading an article about *Crafting*

Comment: I've learned something new! :)  Can I do it with bits of old power tools?

Comment: You do it with a needle and thread, some fabric and maybe some glue. Go for it!